# convert menu buttons to a dropdown menu for small screen (Angular2)

Tags: html, css, angular, drop-down-menu

I am trying to convert a menu of buttons to a dropdown menu to fit the small screen. I have this following menu HTML:

```
<ul>
    <button>Button1</button>
    <button>Button2</button>
    <button>Button3</button>
    <button>Button4</button>
</ul>
```

I have a few separate CSS for each screen size, but I only have one set of HTML. How do I make the buttons into a drop down list for small screen size?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
    <li><button>Button1</button></li>
    <li><button>Button2</button></li>
    <li><button>Button3</button></li>
    <li><button>Button4</button></li>
</ul>
```

this is the basic structure to create a dropdown menu.
You can add dropdown effects usin css styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<ul>
    <li><button>Button1</button></li>
    <li><button>Button2</button></li>
    <li><button>Button3</button></li>
    <li><button>Button4</button></li>
</ul>
```